# Избавиться от внутренних массивов PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив  вида

```
array(177) { [0]=> array(1) { ["html_title_1"]=> string(13) "О школе" } [1]=> array(1) { ["html_desc_1"]=> string(9) "123123555" } [2]=> array(1) { ["html_keyw_1"]=> string(0) "" }
```

как его привести к единому массиву без внутренних, сохранив отношение ключ => значение вложенных массивов, т.е.

```
array(177) { ["html_title_1"]=> string(13) "О школе" ["html_desc_1"]=> string(0) "" ["html_keyw_1"]=> string(0) ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array1=array( 0=> array ( "html_title_1"=> "О школе" ), 1=> array ( "html_desc_1"=> "123123555" ), 2=> array("html_keyw_1"=> "11") );

var_dump($array1);

$array2=array();

    foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
    {
    $val1=key($value);
    $val2=current($value);      
    $array2[$val1]=$val2;
    }
    echo "<br>";

var_dump($array2);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это именно то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ar = array(
array("html_title_1"=> "О школе"),
array("html_desc_1"=> "123123555" )); 

print_r(call_user_func_array(array_merge, $ar));
```

результат

```
Array
(
    [html_title_1] => О школе
    [html_desc_1] => 123123555
)
```

Comment: Немного не то. Мне нужно это все запихнуть не в одно значение массива. а чтобы был массив из N элементов, где ключем будет соответствующй ключ подмассива а значение - соответственно то, которое в подмассиве.

Comment: По сути должен получиться массив где каждый элемент выглядит так:  ["html_title_1"]=> string(13) "О школе".

Comment: @DaVinchi я, правда, не понял разницу в результатах со вторым ответом :(

Comment: У вас в массиве на выходе 1 элемент, где ключ - [html_title_1], а все остальное получилось его значением. Мне же нужны были все элементы вложенных массивов обособлено с сохранением внутренних отношений "ключ"=>"значение". В самом вопросе, где я указывал как оно должно выглядеть, видно, что в конечном массиве должно быть так же 177 элементов, как и во входящем, но без промежуточных подмассивов.

Comment: @DaVinchi я не смог найти отличий  https://eval.in/532989